# Android: detect reason for wakeup

Tags: android

My BroadcastReceiver listens for ACTION_SCREEN_ON events and works well. But is there any way for me to discover **what** or **who** has been waking up the phone? Was it the power button? Was it the alarm clock? Was it XYZ?